# LEFT Function to get String MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have two columns which is `Year` and `Month`. So I display it into table:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year) - @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Month)
```

The result is: `2019-1`, `2019-2`, `2019-3`, ff. 
I want to change the view on the table to become: `1901`, `1902`, `1903`

How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this(assuming the year and month is string, if not string please add .ToString()):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year.Substring(2) + item.Month.PadLeft(2, '0'))
```

Comment: If `item.Month` is an integer, you could then use `item.Month.ToString("00")`